# dynamic multidimensional array in ref class c++

Tags: c++, .net, arrays, c++-cli

I would be grateful if somebody tell me how should I declare a dynamic multidimensional array in ref class? Can somebody post a sample code?

Comment: Well, do you want this in C++ or C++/CLI? Two very different code samples there.

Comment: @user Have you considered using `std::vector<std::vector>` ?

Comment: In cli please. I'm writing in .net visual c++. I don't know how to declare a dynamicly std::vector array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford array reallocations, then use the `array` type.

You can either use the "array of arrays" construction

```
/// Declaration
array<array<SomeType>^>^ arr;

/// Inititalization

arr = gcnew array<array<SomeType>^> (NumElts1);

for(int i=0 ; i < NumElts1 ; i++)
{
  arr[i] = gcnew array<SomeType> (NumElts2);
}
```

or just the multidimensional ones:

```
array<SomeType, NumDims> ^ Arr =
        gcnew array<SomeType, NumDims>(NumElts1, NumElts2, ....);
```

Everything is garbage-collected so you don't worry about destroying them.

If you really need the "dynamic" arrays, then you might look for `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` and use "List of Lists".  Lists have the ToArray() method.

EDIT:

The `array` type in C++/CLI is a template:

```
template<typename T, int NumDims = 1>
ref class array: System::Array
{
    // black magic here
}
```

So you may use it for 1D-array without second argument.

```
array<SomeType>^ Arr = gcnew array<SomeType>(SizeOfThisArray);
```

Comment: can i declare a multidemensional array looking like you second sample, but without numDims (i want to change them dynamicly)?

Comment: This way you cannot. It is "too dynamic". What's wrong with just using Lists and accurate indexing of a lower fixed-dimensional array?

Comment: Ok. So can I use then a singledimensional array declaration without numDims?

Comment: Sure, there's a default value for number of dimensions and it is 1. See my edit. array is a template derived from System::Array